# NetBeans Platform: Entity class error

Tags: java, jpa, entity, netbeans-platform

Up to this point I have had a fully functional NetBeans Platform application with a single screen that utilized Shipvia entity class through the following code:

```
import entity.Shipvia;
import entity.Route;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class RetrieveResultList {

    public static List RetrieveResultList (String tablename){
        EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EntityLibraryPU").createEntityManager();
        System.out.println("NAMED QUERY:>"+tablename+".findAll");
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(tablename+".findAll");
        List<Shipvia> resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

As you can see I create a dynamic query based on the table name passed. So if the user opens a ShipviaTopComponent, it will call Shipvia.findAll (see part of entity class below).

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SHIPVIA")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Shipvia.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Shipvia c")
});
```

My goal is to have a second screen, called RouteTopComponent utilize Route entity class

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROUTE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Route.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Route c")
});
```

However, here is the error I am getting when I try to open the Route screen:

```
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: Route.findAll not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(EJBQueryImpl.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1043)
    at com.demo.viewer.RetrieveResultList.RetrieveResultList(RetrieveResultList.java:23)
    at com.demo.viewer.RoutesTopComponent.<clinit>(RoutesTopComponent.java:40)
Caused: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
```

Line 40 of RouteTopComponent is:

```
List<Route> resultList = RetrieveResultList.RetrieveResultList("Route");
```

It puzzles me as to why it works fine opening ShipviaTopComponent and finds Shipvia.findAll, but not RouteTopComponent/Route.findAll ?

Comment: Note: I recommend to stick to the Java code conventions and start method names with small letter.

Comment: Can you show your persistence.xml?

Comment: @Puce You, Sir, are a genius! Feel free to actually post that as an answer, because you are 100% correct! I have ommited the Route.class from my Persistence.xml ! Also, I appreciate the small-letter convention reminder! It's been a while and for some reason I thought it was cap-letter method names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you have to list the entity classes explicitly in the persistence.xml file if you are using RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction-type/ running JPA in Java SE environment.